# wix installer reboot during installation

Tags: wix

My installer have to enable windows features and it can happen that it has to close the service via the power shell command that require reboot. I am tring in this way: but it only show dialog with information to break instalation and close installer.

I am tring ScheduleReboot and ForceReboot but nothing causes a reboot and recovery.

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <ScheduleReboot After="InstallInitialize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I read that during the reboot should create some registry that allows you to return to the installation and continue it. but I don't know maybe the firewall is blocking me.

Comment: [Have you checked this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166186/wix-burn-after-restart-force-reboot-continuing-installation).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I need restart after instalation file in wix, not in bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at this related question: [Resume installing after restart in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218785/resume-installing-after-restart-in-wix).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately it show how do that for ExePackage and in bootstrapper. MsiPackage doesnt have property <ExitCode>. I am not able to put it anywhere in the wix.